# Use R switch for less than or greater than?

Tags: r

I've used switch for some easy conditionals where variables *equal* various values, but can't figure out how I would use it for less than or greater than conditionals such as

```
if (thedate >= as.Date("1981-01-20") & thedate < as.Date("1989-01-20")) {
  thepres <- "Reagan"}
if (thedate >= as.Date("1989-01-20") & thedate < as.Date("1993-01-20")) {
  thepres <- "George HW Bush"}
if (thedate >= as.Date("1993-01-20") & thedate < as.Date("2001-01-20")) {
  thepres <- "Clinton"}
if (thedate >= as.Date("2001-01-01") & thedate < as.Date("2009-01-20")) {
  thepres <- "George W Bush"}
if (thedate >= as.Date("2009-01-01")) {
  thepres <- "Obama"}
```

(I know those should be nested ifelse statements but I find more than 3 or 4 difficult to code & follow).

Is there some way to use switch for situations like this, or do I have to go the nested ifelse route? (Or just leave it wildly inefficient like this)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `cut` is pretty good for situations like this. (I didn't include all of the presidents, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
thedate <- as.Date("1982-02-01")
thepresident <- cut(thedate, 
    c(as.Date("1981-01-20"), as.Date("1989-01-20"), as.Date("1993-01-20")), 
    labels=c("Reagan", "George HW Bush"), right=F)
```

Also, note that this returns a factor, so you may want to convert to a string.

Comment: Thanks, works a lot better than endless nested if statements.